# android putextra for future notification

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, extra

I'm new with setting future notification for user in my android application
I'm not getting the putExtra string while service class call on particular date for which notification set using alarmmanager.

**Activity Class**

```
utility.setInternalBroadcastNotification(*DYNAMIC_FUTUREDATE*, *DYNAMIC_MESSAGE*);
```

**Utility Class**

```
public void setInternalBroadcastNotification(String eventAlertDateTime, String eventNotificationMessage) {
    try {
        if (!eventAlertDateTime.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !eventNotificationMessage.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, InternalBroadcastReceiver.class);
            myIntent.putExtra("message", eventNotificationMessage);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(getDefaultLocale());
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss", getDefaultLocale());
            Date eventAlertTime = simpleDateFormat.parse(eventAlertDateTime);
            calendar.setTime(eventAlertTime);

            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**InternalBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent intet = new Intent(context, InternalMessageHandler.class);
intet.putExtra("message", intent.getStringExtra("message"));
    context.startService(intet);
}
```

**InternalMessageHandler extends Service**

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<service android:name=".util.InternalMessageHandler" />

    <receiver android:name=".util.InternalBroadcastReceiver" />
```

Here in last from Service class I can't get the message string.

Comment: your receiver called..???

Comment: Yes, all working fine and I can debug upto **onStartCommand** on service but not found extras.

Comment: try bundle to pass and get values..!!

Comment: try to pass  it through a Bundle like: Bundle b = new bundle(); b.putString("message",eventNotificationMessage); myIntent.putExtras(b); and retrieve it like: intent.getStringExtras("message");

Comment: @ManishJain you have to pass message to receiver ?? or service ??

Comment: @Opiatefuchs it not working return null

Comment: what if You try to retrieve the values inside the receiver and pass it to the service via receiver? Does this work? Does Pr38y answer work?

Comment: I already tried that Opiatefuchs

Answer (score 0):

Because message  has been added to `pendingIntent` for broadcast. And when the receiver is called, message hasn't been passed to `InternalMessageHandler`.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
Intent intet = new Intent(context, InternalMessageHandler.class);
intet.putExtra("message", intent.getStringExtra("message"););
context.startService(intet);
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but on service side @Override
 public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

  Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
  String message = intent.getStringExtra("message"); extras and message return null

Comment: are you getting message in `onReceive()`?

Comment: Yes I am, tried same as you suggest earlier, but no luck\

Comment: any help please...!?!

Comment: Yes, I just change **InternalMessageHandler extends IntentService** and extras found on **@Override
 protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {}**